# Мерцание before на Windows XP

Tags: html, css, hover, windows-xp

http://fdmmebel.xn----9sbcmm5bu9h.xn--p1ai/catalog/spalni/kollektsii-spalen/spalnya-claudia/ - пример страницы.

На всех браузерах нет проблемы, на XP происходит мерцание при наведении, в браузере Yandex

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iAw8bitM4sVg4yxwsdeBZQJbqx9e7Kwg

Comment: а причём здесь вообще Windows XP?

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев у клиента наблюдается проблема именно на XP

Comment: Вы проверяли в разных ОС? может проблема всё же в версии браузера?